# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string 'Client' when using Recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am trying to create a `Stacked Bar` from `Recharts` but I get the title error. The thing here is that locally in a separate React project is working properly but when I try to implement it in a legacy code is shows this error. Does it have any connection with the implementation or is there any obvious error in my code?

My data are:

```
Values: [
 { Other: 1000,
   Client: 40,
   period: "2021"
   transactions: 10
 },
 { Other: 4000,
   Client: 10,
   period: "2021"
   transactions: 30
 },
 { Other: 10500,
   Client: 20,
   period: "2021"
   transactions: 40
 }
]
```

And my component is like this:

```
<ComposedChart
   data={mappedValues}
   margin={{
   top: 20,
   right: 80,
   bottom: 20,
   left: 20,
   }}
 >
 <CartesianGrid stroke="#EBF0FA" vertical={false} />
 <XAxis
   dataKey="periodFixed"
   axisLine={false}
   tickLine={false}
   tick={<CustomizedAxisTick />}
 />
 <YAxis
    yAxisId="left"
    axisLine={false}
    tickLine={false}
    tickFormatter={formatYAxis}
    stroke="rgba(99, 110, 131, 0.5)"
 />
 <YAxis
   yAxisId="right"
   orientation="right"
   axisLine={false}
   tickLine={false}
   stroke="rgba(99, 110, 131, 0.5)"
 />
 <Tooltip />
 {legendFlag ? (
   <Legend
     wrapperStyle={{
     paddingTop: "25px",
     paddingLeft: "10px",
    }}
   />
  ) : null}

  /* the below part with the stacked bars is throwing the error */
  <Bar dataKey="Client" stackId="a" fill="#23AC70" />
  <Bar dataKey="Others" stackId="a" fill="#003972" />
  <Line
    type="linear"
    yAxisId="right"
    dataKey="transactions"
    stroke="#ADD868"
    dot={false}
  />
</ComposedChart>
```

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Perhaps this is because the `yAxisId` property is missing from the `Bar`. Can you give a link to a https://codesandbox.io/ with an example?

Comment: @Andrey well I did that and nothing changed! It's probably issue with the implementation of this component into an old project because locally it works.